# AWS Lambda behaviour when execution is waiting an async operation?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, .net-core, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

Let say APIGateway triggers a function(handler) which awaits 10 secs

```
public async Task<APIGatewayProxyResponse> Get(APIGatewayProxyRequest request, ILambdaContext context){
     var x = await Wait10Async();
     return SomeAPIGatewayProxyResponse;
}
```

**Q1:** What happens to this container(execution environment) when `await`returns the control flow to the **function handler itself?** Obviously Lambda waits for Task to complete before returning to the APIGateway, but during this 10 sec does the container(or whatever) accept and execute more `Get` functions?

The reason behind the question is AWS Lambda has 1000 concurrent execution limitations and it said every execution runs in separate containers therefore it makes me question this scenario:

**1 -** APIGateway receives 1000 simultaneous request and starts 1000 Lambda handlers which completes after 10 seconds

**2 -** 3 second after the first requests(before they complete) another let say 100 request come to APIGateway. All lambda containers are exhausted in this case.

Is this what happens or `await` has a magic to solve this? I know how `await` doesn`t block the loop in classic view applications. But how does it behave in Lambda execution environment?

Comment: AFAIC using API Gateway with lambda means a new execution environment for each request, and until the whole lambda handler returns, lambda is still running.

Comment: @zaitsman dont you think this contradicts the 'warm' start case of lambdas? If you fire say 1 lambda then it takes a initial setup time. Consider this
0) Some Warm up with initial call
1) Fire 1 lambda (which returns after 10 sec) 
2) During this 10 sec fire another lambda before the first one returns
3) Your approach suggest second handler will create another container and therefore needs cold start setup time. However its not slow eventhough it is initialized in a new container by theory. 

What do you say?

Comment: The container does not accept and execute other invocations during an `await` or `sleep` or anything similar. A single container will never handle more than one invocation at a time.

Comment: @MarkB Ok but this still leaves a question mark to what I mentioned in my second comment. If every fire results in a new container then why DONT those containers suffer from cold start ?

Comment: They do suffer from cold start, unless you had already created several containers earlier and some were sitting idle.

Comment: @CanSahin You'd have to define 'cold start'. I have little concrete knowledge of how AWS lambda works internally, but i would imagine that the runtime environment is separate from your code environment, and your code is sitting in some form of s3 storage or similar - when your lambda is being invoked, an already existing environment is getting connected to s3, runs your code, exits, disconnects from that storage and then returns to the pool. e.g. execution units don't have a 'cold start' issue, the delay is minimal - just getting and running the right code.